# finding path from tof left to bottom right in 2d array of 1's and 0's

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have 2-D array of 1 and 0's.where top left corner and bottom right corner is filled with 1 and rest of index is filled with 0 and 1.

`a[][]= {{1,1,0,0,1}{0,1,1,0,0}{0,1,0,1,0}{0,1,1,1,1}}` .

write a program/algorithm that will return the other 2-D array of same size, contain the path from start to end.

`output[][]={{1,1,0,0,0}{0,1,0,0,0}{0,1,0,0,0}{0,1,1,1,1}}`.

please help me out for above issue. Also the program should work for other sequence of input.

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Another homework for the day :)

Comment: @vish4071 [Homework questions are not a problem here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/161469). The lack of research effort, on the other hand, is...

Comment: yes, exactly, btw... @Santosh, use bfs.

Comment: @amit ,why you edited my question, what's the wrong with you. why it is wrong.

Comment: The question has been asked me in interview. there i have provided the solution but they rejected my solution.

Comment: Can you post your solution? Maybe there is a little bug in it.

Comment: @flown , i have checked in my code in github.  https://github.com/sancha38/InterviewQuestion/tree/Interview1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can provide you with a cleaner version of the backtracking algorithm. Her you go:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Backtrack {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int[][] inputArray = {
                { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 } };
        int[][] findPath = findPath(inputArray);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(findPath));

    }

    public static int[][] findPath(int[][] maze) {
        int[][] solution = new int[maze.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
            solution[i] = new int[maze[i].length];
        }
        if (!findPath(maze, solution, 0, 0)) {
            System.out.println("Didn't find a solution.");
        }
        return solution;
    }

    private static boolean findPath(int[][] maze, int[][] solution, int x, int y) {
        if (0 <= y && y < maze.length && 0 <= x && x < maze[y].length) {
            if (y == maze.length - 1 && x == maze[y].length - 1) {
                solution[y][x] = 1;
                return true;
            } else if (solution[y][x] != 1 && maze[y][x] == 1) {
                solution[y][x] = 1;
                if (findPath(maze, solution, x, y + 1)
                        || findPath(maze, solution, x + 1, y)
                        || findPath(maze, solution, x - 1, y)
                        || findPath(maze, solution, x, y - 1)) {
                    return true;
                }
                solution[y][x] = 0;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```